# Rational Powers in Arbitrary Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be any field.  Suppose we say that $a^{1/n}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is the set of solutions in $\mathbb{F}$ to $p(x)=x^{n}-a$.  Also, suppose that for any subset $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathbb{F}$ and $m\in \mathbb{N}$, we say that $\mathcal{A}^{m}$ is the set of $m$th powers of elements of $\mathcal{A}$.

Is it true that $(a^{1/n})^{m}=(a^{m})^{1/n}$ for all $m,n$ coprime?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If they aren't coprime, then $2^{1/2}$ is empty in $\mathbb{Q}$, but $4^{1/2}$ is not empty?

Comment: Even in the coprime case one inclusion is trickier than I thought...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may assume $a\ne0$. Let $x\in (a^m)^{1/n}$, i.e. $x^n=a^m$. Let $l,k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $ln+km=1$. Then $x=y^m$ where $y=a^lx^k$ and $y^n=a$, thus $x\in (a^{1/n})^m$. The other inclusion $(a^{1/n})^m\subseteq (a^m)^{1/n}$ is trivial.

Comment: Oops I misread the question @Adayah

Comment: I think you meant to write that $y^{m}=x$.

Comment: Also, can you share any insight into how you thought to construct $y$ like this?  I'll accept your answer in any case.

Comment: Often with these kind of questions when we are given coprime numbers it is useful to write down a Bezout identity $ln+km=1$. Since want to write $x$ in a certain way, we then consider $x=x^{ln+km}$ and simplify/plug in what we know